# Postman - Can you use the {{...}} syntax within a Test script?

Tags: postman

I have an environment variable called "url", the value is a combination of several other variables in the same environment.

Here is the bulk environment variable definition:

```
scheme:http  
server:localhost  
port::55881  
application:/  
url:{{scheme}}://{{server}}{{port}}{{application}}
```

As you can see, url contains other variables.

This works great in the actual request (I'm using `{{url}}` when addressing my service), but when I try to use the same variable in my scripted tests (In the `Tests` tab), I'm getting the un-evaluated version.

```
var serviceUrl = pm.variables.get("url");
console.log(serviceUrl); //Yields {{scheme}}://{{server}}{{port}}{{application}}
```

Is there a way to get the evaluated value inside my tests?

Thanks!

Complete test for more insight:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

var ordrereferanse = jsonData.Ordrereferanse;
tests.OrdreReferanse = ordrereferanse.length > 0;

//Have to do this
var scheme      = pm.variables.get("scheme");
var server      = pm.variables.get("server");
var port        = pm.variables.get("port");
var application = pm.variables.get("application");
var api_key     = pm.variables.get("api_key");

var serviceUrl = scheme + "://" + server + port + application;

//Instead of this - an environment variable defined like this "{{scheme}}://{{server}}{{port}}{{application}}"
//var serviceUrl = pm.variables.get("url");

//remaining test - go to url to verify that the resource is created and the order reference is set
var infoUrl = serviceUrl + "ordreinformasjon/" + ordrereferanse + "?format=json&api_key=" + api_key;

pm.sendRequest(infoUrl, function (err, response) {
    var info = response.json();

    console.log(info);

    tests.OrdreInformasjonOrdreReferanse = info.OrdreReferanse === ordrereferanse;
});
```

Comment: Can you expand of what you're trying to test please? That the serviceUrl is the same as the url being used (without the variables)? Is the `url` entered in the environment file like that?

Answer (score 1):

This would work but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve:

```
var scheme      = pm.variables.get("scheme")
var server      = pm.variables.get("server")
var port        = pm.variables.get("port")
var application = pm.variables.get("application")

console.log(`${scheme}://${server}${port}${application}`)
```

That would log out `http://localhost:55881/` to the console.

The `{{...}}` syntax doesn't work in the way that you had it in the environment file. As it's just storing everything as a `string` so that's why you would get that output.

You could use `{{scheme}}://{{server}}{{port}}{{application}}` as the URL but not in the tests using the same syntax.

---

**UPDATE**

After seeing the update to the question - Could you not combine the separate variables into a single `url` variable and construct the `infoUrl` variable in the following way:

```
var infoUrl = `${pm.variables.get("url")}ordreinformasjon/${ordrereferanse}?format=json&api_key=${pm.variables.get("api_key")}`
```

Then use a different environment file with the same `url` key but with a different value if you need to point the request at a `staging` or `production` URL.

I've also noticed that you're using the older `tests` syntax rather than the newer [pm.test()](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts) syntax, that might clean up some of the code for you.

Comment: My hope was for pm.variables.get(...) to do the actual evaluation of the variable before returning the final value "http://localhost:55881/". Evidently that's not the way it's working, so I was hoping there was some overload or other function that could do the evaluation for me, so that I don't have to update my tests if I change my encapsulating variables.

Comment: The Postman `pm.environment.get()` function is just doing exactly that "get me the value of that key from the environment file" Unfortunately, everything is stored as a string. Can you update the question with an example of one of your tests? It seems like something that can be done but I don't know what your time looks like.

Comment: I don't think it will give more clarity to my question to post my test, it's after all the first scripted Postman-test I have made. But I think it would be a valuable addition to an excellent tool if I could use variables in the script, without knowing their "internal" value.

Comment: I/everyone reading this doesn't know how you're trying implement a test to evaluate the url string and more information in the question helps you get an answer or a possible solution. By definition, it brings clarity to the question. I think I can provide a solution for you but without seeing any tests (doesn't matter if it the first one) i'm just guessing.

Comment: Ok, thanks Danny, I extended the question with my complete test.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look.

Comment: Can ask why you’re separating the url out in the way that you have in the environment file. Could you have a single file for say `local` with the full url stored as a variable and then a different one for `staging` which has a different url value set. That way you’re only changing the env file in a single place rather then in multiple tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163438/discussion-between-danny-dainton-and-haraldv).